# Using ajax with django failed with 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to prevent refreshing the website when someone hit the like button on the page.

Since I am new to ajax, I've tried some method to link Django with ajax. I know that I should pass `csrftoken` to Django when using form or ajax, but it turns out not working. Chrome console shows the error message of `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` with the current page url and the `csrftoken`, something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/event/TuffGeRykWO2jZAEGl6DNIxmwXH3x5tMjCvx6SHv5TsS7DpOCB3j4fBvF0BEFamu`

And here's are my code of ajax

```
// pug file 
#likebutton(style="background-image: url('/static/file/like-bg-n.png')")
  button(type="image", src="{% static 'file/like-bg-n.png' %}", alt="Submit Form",name="event_id", value="{{ event_detail.id }}")
    span#like-img
{% endif %}
script.
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#likebutton").on("click", function() {
      like_handler("{% url 'like' %}", "{{ csrf_token }}", "{{ event_detail.id }}");
    })
  })
```

```js
// js file
function like_handler(CSRF, URL, event_id) {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: CSRF
    }
  });
  var csrftoken = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: URL,
    data: {
      event_id: event_id, 
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      if (data.status == '200') {
        console.log('success')
        if (data.add) {
          $('#likebutton').attr("src", "/static/file/like-bg-y.png")
          $('#member').append(
            "<a herf='{% url 'profile' request.user.userextend.pk %}'> \
            <img class='member interested' src='{{ request.user.userextend.img.url }}'/></a>"
          )
        } else if (data.remove) {
          $('#likebutton').attr("src", "/static/file/like-bg-n.png")
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Error: ajax error");
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```py
# view.py
def like_view(request):
  if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST
    event = get_object_or_404(EventsBoard, id=data.get('event_id'))
    
    if event.likes.filter(id=request.user.userextend.id).exists():
      event.likes.remove(request.user.userextend)
      return JsonResponse({
        'add': False,
        'remove': True,
        'status': '200'
      })
    else:
      event.likes.add(request.user.userextend)
      receiver = event.host.user
      sender = request.user
      notification = SiteNotification.objects.create(
        text = sender.userextend.full_name + "is interest in your event",
        event = event,
        for_user = receiver,
        from_user = sender
      )
      notification.save()
      return JsonResponse({
        'add': True,
        'remove': False,
        'status': '200'
      })
  return JsonResponse({
    'status': '404',
    'error_message': '[Error] Not ajax request'
  })
```

I'm not sure where is the problem, thank you in advance!

Comment: `like_handler(CSRF, URL, event_id)` and `like_handler("{% url 'like' %}", "{{ csrf_token }}", "{{ event_detail.id }}")` do you notice something here? You aren't passing your arguments in the correct order... Plus you are meant to set the CSRF token on the headers of the request you make, not send it in the data.

Comment: Oh...I really didn't notice that, I'll modify it, thanks a lot!